# How to convert string with dict into actual dict object?

Tags: python, json, python-2.x

I have a string output as this (its a string return from a Popen command):

```
p = Popen(ZOO_CMD, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
print output
```

the variable `output` prints:

```
{
  "animals": [
    {
      "animalCount": 1
    }
  ],
  "zooName": "zoo1"
}
```

I've tried to load the string as such

```
json_dict = json.loads(output)
print json_dict['animals']
```

I am getting this traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./zoo_dump", line 44, in <module>
    json_dict = json.loads(output)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 338, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: The title was inaccurate as originally asked; this string is **not** in JSON format.

Comment: another point: single quotes `'zoo1'` are not valid json format

Comment: @MigB that was a typo

Comment: It's still not valid JSON because it has a comma where one isn't allowed (at the end of `"animalCount": 1,` when there aren't more items following).

Comment: See the code with a corrected string at https://ideone.com/ug3cAb, working perfectly.

Comment: You keep editing the string you're starting with. **Now** your string is valid json so you should no longer get this error.

Comment: @ealeon, if you can't give us a string that's actually valid JSON for which `json.loads()` **really** generates this error, I don't know how we can help you. BTW, `print(repr(output))` is more helpful than `print(output)`, insofar as it includes nonprintable characters that can get lost otherwise. You might also try to follow the example I gave of an ideone.com link that generates the error in a context where we can fork/edit/rerun. (Of course, in my example, ideone.com *doesn't* generate the error, but that's expected, because the JSON given is valid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to make it valid JSON and then parse, but that will tend to be error prone unless you have very predictable json errors.

Instead, you could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely evaluate it into python:

```
import ast 

s = '''{
  "animals": [
    {
      "animalCount": 1,
    }
  ],
  "zooName": 'zoo1'
}'''

ast.literal_eval(s)
```

**Result**

```
{'animals': [{'animalCount': 1}], 'zooName': 'zoo1'}
```

Comment: Just changing the quotes isn't sufficient to make it valid JSON, one also needs to remove the trailing comma after the `1`.